# How do I fix a wrapped seatbelt?

Tags: repair

I've got a carseat that has a looped seatbelt and I have fought with it for the last hour. I don't want to send it in, I want to fix it myself. Anyone have any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Usually, all that's happened is that the buckle has slid over a partial twist in the belt. With enough wiggling, you should be able to push the buckle to one side or the other of the fold. Note that if you push it to the wrong side you may need to deliberately do this again to get the buckle twisted back onto the original side of the belt.

Annoying, but common and not a big deal if you're patient and persistent.